# Looping with conditional statement

Tags: java, loops, conditional-statements

Hi i want to learn how to do java loop that will determined the number if it is an odd or even like

```
   1st value: 8
   2nd value: 15

output:
    8 is even
    9 is odd
    10 is even
    11 is odd
    12 is even
    13 is odd
    14 is even
    15 is odd
```

Comment: [The Java Tutorials - The for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("First value: ");

int start = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());//Gets the first number

System.out.print("Second value: ");

int end = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());//Gets the second number

for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
    if(i%2==0){//When the number is divided by 2, it gives a remainder of 0. Modulus helps us get the remainder.
        System.out.println(i+" is even");
    }else{//Doesn't satisfy the first condition. It must be odd.
        System.out.println(i+" is odd");
    }
}
```

We use a Scanner to read the user input, then use a `for` loop and leverage modulus (`%`). Modulus calculates the remainder of a number after dividing it by a certain number. If a number divided by 2 gives a remainder of 0, that means it is divisible by 2. We can construct an `if` statement to check whether it is divisble.

**Test Run**

```
First value: 1
Second value: 10
1 is odd
2 is even
3 is odd
4 is even
5 is odd
6 is even
7 is odd
8 is even
9 is odd
10 is even
```

Comment: @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer Thank you :D

Comment: I'd personally comment it more (to explain your thoughts) and break up the lines a bit (little hard to read), but seems pretty comprehensive to me.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use a for loop it's simple.

```
for(int i=8;i<=15;i++){
if(i%2==0){
System.out.println(i+"is even");
}else{


System.out.println(i+"is odd");
}
}
```

And I expect you know how to ask inputs so just pass it on the place of 8 and 15

Answer (score 0):

### The short version:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cakN0XC6CcQ

Use  `number % 2 == 0` for even numbers.

### The long version:

```java
// Create a new Scanner() to scan System.in
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// Get the two inputs
int first = scanner.nextInt();
int second = scanner.nextInt();

// Start i as the first number
// While it is less than or equal to the second
// Add one each time
for(int i = first; i <= second; i++) {

    // Is there a remainder from dividing i by 2?
    // If no, it's even
    boolean even = i % 2 == 0;

    // Print it
    System.out.println(i + " is even: " + even);
}

    scanner.close();
```

Comment: The user is saying he will ask for 2 inputs so your answer is not correct please edit it and show him how to append the input range to a list

Comment: Sorry @YeshwinVermaTheProgrammer I didn't read that (have to be more careful!). I've amended the answer.